# Get the respective WebView of the link

Tags: android, webview

With android studio I'm creating an app for feed and I have a ListView where there are the titles and the previews of the articles (preview = the little description [here](http://gazzetta.it/rss/Home.xml)). Is there a way that when you click on the item in the list , you get the respective webview of the link? In this way I can get images, title, pubdate and the FULL description of the article. How can I do it?

Comment: You want to open the article in a webview or do you want the rss feed of the article?

Comment: it doesn't matter. I just want to get all the item there are in the links in that site (title,full description,images...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an item from the rss feed:

```
<item>
    <position>1 - 42</position>
    <title><![CDATA[Ibracadabra, tacco devastante Poi Cavani per il volo Psg /  Vd 1 - 2 ]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[Ibracadabra, tacco devastante Poi Cavani per il volo Psg / Vd 1-2<br/>
    <b>I parigini battono 4-0 il Bastia e staccano in testa il gruppo. Formidabile prestazione dello svedese che apre le marcature con un incredibile gesto tecnico e poi raddoppia di testa. Nella ripresa lascia all'uruguaiano che fissa il risultato con un'altra doppietta</b>
    <br/>]]></description>
    <link>http://www.gazzetta.it/Calcio_Estero/Ligue1/19-10-2013/ligue-1-ibracadabra-tacco-devastante-psg-volo-201391407179.shtml</link>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Alessandro Grandesso(twitter @calciofrancese)]]></dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.gazzetta.it/Calcio_Estero/Ligue1/19-10-2013/ligue-1-ibracadabra-tacco-devastante-psg-volo-201391407179.shtml</guid>
    <category domain="http://www.gazzetta.it">Calcio</category>
    <pubDate>Sun, 20 Oct 2013 00:15:16 +0200</pubDate>
    <enclosure url="http://images2.gazzettaobjects.it/methode_image/2013/10/19/Calcio/Foto%20Calcio%20-%20Trattate/024-132662-01-02-20131019-154139--630x365.jpg"/>
    <enclosure url="http://images2.gazzettaobjects.it/methode_image/2013/10/19/Calcio/Foto%20Calcio%20-%20Trattate/024-132662-01-02-20131019-154139--630x365_230x130.jpg"/>
    <enclosure url="http://images2.gazzettaobjects.it/methode_image/2013/10/19/Calcio/Foto%20Calcio%20-%20Trattate/024-132662-01-02-20131019-154139--630x365_160x90.jpg"/>
    <enclosure url="http://images2.gazzettaobjects.it/methode_image/2013/10/19/Calcio/Foto%20Calcio%20-%20Trattate/024-132662-01-02-20131019-154139--630x365_230x130.jpg"/>
</item>
```

Since you're already getting the title and description, I'm guessing you're successfully parsing the feed.

You can get the link of the article from the `<link>` tag.

You can get the images from the `<enclosure>` tag.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the content of the article.

Comment: So if I want to have the entire description (have you seen there is only a bit of description?) I just find a good rss site ?

Comment: You have to find a website that provides an rss feed for the content of their articles, not just the title and small description.